# Track user-id in google analitycs using ajax

Tags: ajax, google-analytics

I have enabled user-id in Google Analitycs, but implementing in my templates can be difficult.
Here is the case:

ga(create...) is in the main template.

I get $ajax.userid from my app by ajax call. Not all templates use ajax, so there should be the 'normal' code. So what I want achieve is:
log GA the same way like now, but when there is a Ajax reponse with $ajax.userid I

```
ga(create,id,{userID: ajax.userid})
ga(set,'dimension1',ajax.userid);
```

and it is logged with user-id to GA.

Maybe there should be a timeout in main template, so when there is no GA object in 5 second it creates it but without ajax? Any hints? I don't want to double the stats - here is a risk.

Anybody has an experience with it - if it can be done with GA or only with some JS hacks?

Comment: Maybe multitrackers help somehow?